# Lose the [statistics] tag?

Tags: feature-request

The [statistics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag appears to be a popular meta-tag, which is to be be avoided.

Should it be deleted and banned?

Comment: Should be removed, but I'd ask SE to do that as retagging manually would be quite disruptive.

Answer (score 6):

I use the [statistics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag when someone is skeptical of statistical data. It doesn't look to me as it's a worse usage of a tag than, say, [psychology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology), or [alternative-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-medicine).

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably one of the "guilty" users, but I find the tag useful to note questions where the key evidence is or should be about the interpretation of statistical data. I don't think this makes it a *meta-tag*. Perhaps I just need to see a better explanation of why using it is a problem, or perhaps a better, clearer explanation of the concept of meta-tag.

I think we would be worse off without it. It clearly distinguishes some questions from others, though it applies to a wide range of questions. Perhaps it is a unique problem on *this* site because, to some degree, it classifies the sort of *evidence* required to address a question not just the content of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree [that it should be deleted and banned]. Let’s see what the other mods think.